# Why does this code only use the last number in the list as an answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Oct 8, 2015
# TriviaGame

import Question

Questions = ["How many licks does it take to get to the center of a Tootsie Pop™ ?",
             "What does the scouter say about his power level", ]
answer1 = ["10", "Over 9000"]
answer2 = ["20", "1000"]
answer3 = ["30", "10000"]
answer4 = ["The world may never know", "5000"]
correct = [4, 1]
questionList = list()
player1 = 0
player2 = 0
x = 0
turns = 2

while x < turns:
    q = Question.Question(Questions[x], answer1[x], answer2[x], answer3[x], answer4[x], correct[x])
    questionList.append(q)
    x += 1

turn = 0
while turn < turns:

    if turn % 2 != 0:
        print("Player 2 Answer ")
        questionList[turn].ask()
        response = int(input("Enter a number"))
        q.correct(response, player2)

        if q.correct(response, player2):
            player2 += 1


    else:

        questionList[turn].ask()
        response = int(input("Enter a number"))
        q.correct(response, player1)

        if q.correct(response, player1):
            player1 += 1
    turn += 1

    if q.correct(response,player1):
        print("Nice job. You got it right")
    else:
        print("Your wrong")
```

The code above is supposed to ask the user a question and have them put in an integer depending on which answer is correct. The answers are set as such

```
correct = [4, 1]
```

The problem is the answer is always 1 even though the fist answer should be 4.

Edit: Question module

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4, correct_answer):

        self.__question = question
        self.__answer_1 = answer_1
        self.__answer_2 = answer_2
        self.__answer_3 = answer_3
        self.__answer_4 = answer_4
        self.__correct_answer = correct_answer

    def ask(self):
        print(self.__question)
        print("1. " + self.__answer_1)
        print("2. " + self.__answer_2)
        print("3. " + self.__answer_3)
        print("4. " + self.__answer_4)

    def correct(self, response, player1):

        if response == self.__correct_answer:

            return True
        else:

            return False
```

Comment: What is the `Question` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is asking the `Question` in `questionList[turn]`, but you're checking the answer against the `Question` named `q`. That's left over from the earlier loop where you created `questionList` and it will always hold the last question you created.

To make your code work, you need to access the same question both for asking and for checking. Either replace the references to `q` in the last loop with `questionList[turn]` or rebind `q` to the current question somewhere.